# Captured image is stretching when it is taken in landscape mode iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

i am using UIImagePickerController and i captured on image in landscape mode, it is directly converted to Portrait mode but that image is stretching in landscape mode..

can anyone tell me what is the reason

my code is:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   myimageView.image = selectedImage;
   [myimageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 427)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the imageView size is smaller than original image. You can see the original image size by

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(selectedImage.size));
```

So when you try to fir a large image in smaller image View obviously it will be stretch.

i think it may be reason.

Comment: So in that case what needs to be done because even if you increase or manage the size of the image it would still appear stretched @Vakul

Comment: Keep your `UIImageView` height-width ratio equal to your `UIImage` height-width ratio. Ex:- If your image is of 200x300 then make your imageView of 2:3, So it can be 200x300, 100x150, 50x75....!!